# Incorrect image on posting URL

Tags: debugging, url, image-processing, preview

I'm having problems (or at least an strange behavior) when I try to post an URL link from my web page on my facebook's wall profile:

If I copy the complete URL from my website and when I paste on my wall, the thumbnail image (tagged with og:image) preloaded isn't the correct one. But, if I debug the URL with the Open Graph Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) all looks like fine and the "Share Preview" shows the desired image.
After debug the URL I back to my profile and paste the same URL and magically the image on the  preview is the desired.

Can anybody tell me where is the problem or how can my visitors publish my website's links without debug the URL prior to share the link?